# Use debconf to get arbitrary length arrays of user values

Tags: debian, deb

I'm building some deb package files and I've come across a number of instances in which I'd like to get one *or more* arbitrary string values (i.e., NOT multiselect) from a user. Currently I see no way of doing this, and I'm wondering if it's possible.

An example would be in setting up a pool of admin users for a machine. In this case, I might ask:

```
$ Please add a user:
$ 
$ username: someuser
$ password:
$ password set successfully
$ 
$ User "someuser" successfully added. Would you like to add another? [y,n]: y
$
$ username: notheruser
$ password: 
$ password set successfully
$
$ Use "notheruser" successfully added.....
```

Presumably this would yield an array for users and a matching array for passwords. (Note: somewhat contrived example, so I'm not interested in discussions of whether or not this particular use-case is a good idea.)

Is there some community convention for addressing this? Is there a confmodule solution I don't know about?

Comment: @someone thanks for the anonymous downvote without comment....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there doesn't appear to be a good way of doing this. I'm submitting this answer (though not accepting it) as a *possible* solution, and one that I'm probably going to employ in the short term.

You can gather simple array answers as space-separated lists and then just parse them into bash arrays like this:

```
$ read ANS
$ these are four values
$ ANS=($ANS)
$ for a in "${ANS[@]}" do
$     echo "Answer: $a"
$ done
$ 
$ # Outputs:
$ #
$ # Answer: these
$ # Answer: are
$ # Answer: four
$ # Answer: values
```

Obviously if you need to do anything more complex than this, you're screwed. If you want to accept values with spaces in them, you could request that users quote their values and then use `eval` on the incoming value to turn it into an array:

```
$ read ANS
$ these are 'four or five' values
$ eval "ANS=($ANS)"
$ for a in "${ANS[@]}" do
$     echo "Answer: $a"
$ done
$ 
$ # Outputs:
$ #
$ # Answer: these
$ # Answer: are
$ # Answer: four or five
$ # Answer: values
```

Again, not ideal, but that's what I've got so far.